# как достать с iframe youtube продолжительность видео?

Tags: javascript, youtube

Как узнать продолжительность видео?

Comment: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1TsVjvEkc4s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 5):

Никак, политика безопасности браузера не позволит. Для этого есть [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

Comment: я пробовал, но у меня с англ не очень(

Comment: Запрос должен быть таким: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=9bZkp7q19f0&part=contentDetails&client={client_id}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` Тут есть видео как получить ключи и ид разработчика - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg__b_WM5gg